# I'm receiving an error "JsonSerializationException: Could not find member 'logprobs' on object of type 'ChatChoice'." in ChatGPT-Unity package?

Tags: unity-game-engine, openai-api

I'm using Unity 2022.3.8 and a package from https://github.com/srcnalt/OpenAI-Unity to create AI dialogue. My API key is set up, and I've followed several tutorials step by step, but whenever I try to send a message to the AI using the sample scene provided, I'm met with the following error:

"JsonSerializationException: Could not find member 'logprobs' on object of type 'ChatChoice'. Path 'choices[0].logprobs', line 13, position 17. ..."

The error code is significantly longer, and I can post the entire thing if necessary.

The error seems to be generated from this line in a script called Chat GPT (A manager for Chat GPT integration):

`

```
var completionResponse = await openai.CreateChatCompletion(new CreateChatCompletionRequest()
            {
                Model = "gpt-3.5-turbo-0613",
                Messages = messages
                
            });
```

I've tried reformatting this line, and seeing what other data I could add to find what was missing, but I haven't found anything. Is anyone else coming across this error?

Comment: please read: https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/authentication

Answer (score 1):

OpenAI updated their API and logporbs is provided in `ChatCompletions`. To fix the error,

Find DataTypes.cs in Packages/OpenAi Unity/Runtime/DataTypes.cs

Add:

```
public string Logprobs { get; set; }
```

To:

```
public struct ChatChoice
```

```
public struct ChatChoice {
  public string Logprobs { get; set; }
}
```

Source: https://community.openai.com/t/in-unity-encountering-jsonserializationexception-while-using-chatgpt-api/538828/5

Answer (score 0):

The answer above by Anirudh worked for me!